How to find an <input> that has a particular text as sibling in playwright?
I have a form with many elements of the following pattern (ng-star-inserted et al. removed):
<ui-input label="First Name">
    <div>First Name</div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</ui-input>

I would like Playwright to type text into the corresponding box on the form. As I understand it, the Playwright school of thought is to find the inner <input> element and await input.fill("Humbleton").
I've tried:
page.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'First Name' });
page.getByText('First Name').locator('input');
page.getByLabel('First Name').locator('input');
page.getByText('First Name').getByRole('textbox');
page.getByLabel('First Name').getByRole('textbox');

of which none work.
The go-to workaround is to insert a secret, unique-value attribute into the HTML and use the resulting unique XPath. However, I consider this to be cheating and against the spirit of e2e testing, clean code, propriety, and Playwright's philosophy. Is there a Playwrightesque solution?
Finally I used page.keyboard to fill out the form using page.keyboard.press('Tab') to navigate from one field to another, but I have a hunch that this is not as robust and user-oriented as can be.
I feel there must be some overlooked elegant, expressive way to tell Playwright to just fill out the damn 'First Name' box.

For your getByLabel to work, you'd need to use aria-label:
<ui-input aria-label="First Name">

Other of your locators don't work because the input isn't actually a child of the <div>First Name</div> element, which is what .getByText would return.
Also, your <div>First Name</div> doesn't appear to be acting as a clickable label. I'd expect modern, accessible HTML to be something more along the lines of:
<ui-input aria-label="First Name">
  <div>
    <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input
      id="first-name"
      placeholder="Enter your first name"
      autocomplete="off"
      aria-labelledby="first-name"
    >
  </div>
</ui-input>

If you can make your markup more like this, selection becomes straightforward.
But assuming it's out of your control, you can use CSS selectors to find the input by the label attribute, or use .filter() to select a ui-input with particular text.
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.46.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<ui-input label="First Name">
  <div>First Name</div>
  <div>
    <input placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</ui-input>
</body></html>`;

test("Input can be located by First Name", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.locator('[label="First Name"] input').waitFor()

  // or, more "Playwright"-y:
  await page
    .locator("ui-input")
    .filter({hasText: "First Name"})
    .getByRole("textbox").waitFor();
});

Note that these may not work or even be best practice, depending on your full HTML context, which wasn't shown.
And yeah, don't use XPath under almost any circumstances. If you have to avoid user-visible locators for some reason, CSS selectors are cleaner than XPath. Compare the XPath given in this answer against its functionally equivalent CSS selector, and the choice is quite clear:
'//ui-input[@label="First Name"]/descendant::input'
'ui-input[label="First Name"] input'

Then again, neither is optimal. See the docs on best practices, "Prefer user-facing attributes to XPath or CSS selectors".

Try using
page.locator('//ui-input[@label="First Name"]/descendant::input')
as
page.getByLabel('First Name').getByRole('textbox'); is not working.
If this is also not working, Can you check if there is no iframe at the top level of this form?

I'd avoid XPath. It's verbose and nasty to work with--the PW user-visible selectors are best practice, and if you don't want to use those, use CSS selectors instead of XPath.

There is nothing wrong with using xpath in this scenario.It has been used in a non brittle way.

It will most likely endure the future unrelated UI changes in the page.

@VishalAggarwal We've discussed this before, and that goes against Playwright best practices. XPath is hard to read, hard to maintain, and easily leads to brittle selectors. This one is tied to a specific attributes elements that are liable to change when non-user visible aspects of the page change. The goal is to test the user experience, not the programmer experience, and tags and attributes are for programmers, not users. This is a well-established QA testing community standard as of the past 5 years or so.

If you have to use a non-PW best practice .getByRole or .getByLabel, then use CSS selectors instead of XPath. At least the syntax is comprehensible: '//ui-input[@label="First Name"]/descendant::input' is easily translated to 'ui-input[label="First Name"] input' without change in functionality.

personally, i prefer adding testids wherever possible to avoid all the headaches with xpath and css. I was just suggesting a way for the OP to fix his issue. But, i agree with you both @ggorlen and Vishal

Test ids have many of the same problems as XPath, plus some additional ones. They aren't user visible, so you have no guarantee that what you're testing is actually something that matters for the application. Also, they need to be maintained by and require coordination with the dev team and pollute the markup with extra verbosity. It's still best practice to use user-visible selectors.

Testing by test ids is the most resilient way of testing as even if your text or role of the attribute changes, the test will still pass.

QA's and developers should define explicit test ids and query them with page.getByTestId()

Exactly my point +1 Vishal. Also, testids helped me in different projects with several languages testing where testid remains the same in all languages.

The point is moot: user-visible tests are the same in all languages too, they assume even less about implementation details than test ids do.

They are not mutually exclusive. One can use css/xpath with user- visible attributes.
